# Show that $\mu(f)\mu(1/f)\geq\mu(\Omega)^2$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Prove that $\mu(\Omega)^2\leq\int f \,d\mu\int\frac{1}{f}\,d\mu$.

I don't know if that what I did is correct or if it will help to solve the problem, but here it is:

Using the Hölder inequality $\mu(\Omega)=\int_{\Omega} 1 \,d\mu=\int_{\Omega} |f.\frac{1}{f}|\,d\mu\leq (\int_{\Omega}|f|^1\, d\mu)^{\frac{1}{1}}(\int_{\Omega}|\frac{1}{f}|^1\, d\mu)^{\frac{1}{1}}=
\int_{\Omega}f\, d\mu\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{f}\, d\mu$.

I stopped here.

Comment: Note that what you wrote is not the Hölder inequality.  (Hint: $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} \ne 1$.)

Comment: Please try to avoid noninformative titles.

Comment: I did, but someone has edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. Just use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality 
$$\mu(\Omega)=\int_{\Omega} 1 \,d\mu=\int_{\Omega} \left|f^{1/2}\frac{1}{f^{1/2}}\right|\,d\mu\leqslant \left(\int_{\Omega}|f|\, d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{|f|}\, d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Comment: I believe it's spelled "Schwarz", and it's worth noting that this is a special case of Hölder's inequality (take $p=q=2$).

Comment: I change it. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is enough in this case.